# Centering some cell in table + breaking up a cell

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I would like to get a contingency table but I've got 2 problems
* First, I would like to splits my columnname. I've tried this (as you can see below) using \, but that didn't work
* I would like to center the cell containing 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd'. I've tried this for 'a' using multicolumn, but it does not work

```
\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
 \scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|m{4.8cm}|m{4.8cm}|m{4.8cm}|}
    \hline
           &  \textbf{Classified as a keyword\\ by the human} & \textbf{Classified as not a\\ keyword by the human} \\ \hline
            \textbf{Classified as a keyword by the automatic extraction} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{a} & b \\ \hline
            \textbf{Classified as not a keyword by the automatic extraction} & c & d \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Contingency table on results of detection and extraction.}
  \label{prerec}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot go to a newline arbitrarily in a `tabular` environment, unless you use `tabularx`. However, there is luckily a package just to fill this gap, which is `makecell`. You can also change the font style (bold, italics) so it's very handy.

Concerning the centering of the cells, you can create a new column type, but you need to load the `array` package.

I also edited your table a bit: I removed all the vertical lines, since the content is readable without them, they become superfluous and added the `booktabs` that provides commands for adding well-spaced rules.

[image: table figure]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\renewcommand\theadalign{cb}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
 \centering
    \scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{C{4.5cm} C{4.5cm} C{4.5cm}}
\toprule
 & \thead{Classified as a keyword\\by the human} & \thead{Classified as not a\\keyword by the human} \\ \midrule
  \thead{Classified as a keyword by\\the automatic extraction} & a & b \\
  \thead{Classified as not a keyword\\by the automatic extraction} & c & d \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Contingency table on results of detection and extraction.}
  \label{prerec}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```